# Blazor invokeMethodAsync cannot find method

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I'm calling a C# method from Javascript using invokeMethodAsync. I had it working a day ago but it has broken since and no amount of reverting my changes seems to fix it.

Error: `System.ArgumentException: The assembly 'HelloWorld' does not contain a public invokable method with [JSInvokableAttribute("GetCodeFromList")].`

The JS:

```
DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('HelloWorld', 'GetCodeFromList')
    .then(data => {
        data.push(result.codeResult.code);
    }
);
```

The `result.codeResult.code` is the number I want to receive on the C# side. I have already confirmed that the number is correct.

The C#:

```
[JSInvokable]
public void GetCodeFromList(long jsCode)
{
    code = codes.Where(p => p.SecretCode.Equals(jsCode)).FirstOrDefault();
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

I have another .razor file where I have a method also called GetCodeFromList that I also want to be accessible using the same invoke, but I have tried completely removing it and that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You need a `DotNetObjectReference` to call a non static function : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1#instance-method-call

Comment: I think you method needs to be [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1#static-net-method-call) if it is not wrapped in a [DotNetObjectReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1#instance-method-call)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>You will have to change your C# method to static:</s>

**Updated** answer: You will have to pass the reference of the class instance to your javascript method which will use that to call your method.

```cs
public async Task TriggerDotNetInstanceMethod()
{
    objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);  <--- this is the instance reference you have to pass
    result = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("sayHello1", objRef);
}

[JSInvokable]
public void GetCodeFromList(long jsCode)
{
    code = codes.Where(p => p.SecretCode.Equals(jsCode)).FirstOrDefault();
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

And javascript:

```js
<script>
  window.sayHello2 = (dotNetHelper, name) => {
    return dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('GetCodeFromList', name);
  };
</script>
```

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1#instance-method-call) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-instance-method-call) for more info.

Comment: how does this code compile while you can't call  `StateHasChanged();` in a static method ?

Comment: DotNetObjectReference.Create(this) is used to pass an INSTANCE to the javascript.  When it uses that value 'dotNetHelper' to invoke javascript, it invokes an instance function, thus StateHasChanged is valid.